# How to copy data from a specific line in a file to another file via terminal?

Tags: file, terminal

How could i copy all data from e.g line 10 from a file to line 10 to another file using terminal ?

Any help ?

Comment: Do you want to copy a file to another file using terminal?

Comment: Yes, but not all data from the first file. Just from line 10 to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer though , this is how you get the content from a specific file using the sed and awk utility tools.

Here is the usage:

using sed:
    sed '10!d'

using awk:

```
awk 'NR==10' <file-name>
```

NB: Hope the copy part of the question ,will not be any harder.